# Can I combine the 2 marrow animate sequences into one statement and still get the same results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway I can combine the 2 marrow animate sequences into one statement and still get the same results?

```
btnopen.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
var marrow = $(this).find(btnopenarrow);
    marrow.css({'background-position':'bottom center'});
    marrow.stop().animate({marginTop:5}, 100, 'easeOutCubic', function(){
    marrow.stop().animate({marginTop:20}, 300, 'easeOutCubic');
  });
    mlinkopen.css({color:'white'});
});
```

Comment: note: The nested `stop()` is pointless as you are waiting for the previous animation to complete.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that!

Comment: Have you tried chaining them together like you did `stop()` and the first `animate()`? Do that instead of using the second animate in a callback functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations are queued (per element). Just chain them:

```
marrow.css({'background-position':'bottom center'}).stop().animate({marginTop:5}, 100, 'easeOutCubic').animate({marginTop:20}, 300, 'easeOutCubic');
```

As mentioned in comment, the nested `stop` did nothing as you were waiting for the previous animation to complete anyway.

*I am assuming you need the initial `stop` to stop some previous animation. If not, remove that too.*

e.g.

```
marrow.css({'background-position':'bottom center'}).animate({marginTop:5}, 100, 'easeOutCubic').animate({marginTop:20}, 300, 'easeOutCubic');
```